# python udp socket from batch-file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I've a simple code to send a UDP packet to a UDP server.
It works on my Linux Ubuntu machine. 
It also works on my Windows 7 computer running python 2.6.6 via PythonWin or PythonIDE, but when trying to run from a the command shell or batch file it do not work.

I write

```
[full patch]\python.exe [full path]\cl.py
```

and the program run, print statements work but no UDP packet is sent. (checked with WireShark on the windows machine) No other error is indicated.

Is there something special to consider for running from command prompt or batch file?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

port = 12345
ip = "10.30.5.70"
data = "Hello World"

UDPSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.sendto(data, (ip,port))
print "done."
```

Comment: Is your firewall blocking python.exe?

Comment: I'm not sure, (I'm local admin but not system admin on my computer) I did not expect the PythonWin or PythonIDE to work in this case. But I'll try to find out. thanks

Comment: Python is **not** blocked by firewall. When writing the script row by row in python it works.

Answer (score 0):

in windows im pretty sure you dont need to include the 'python.exe' or even 'python' you just enter the name of the python script like this '[full path]\cl.py' this works for me but I have  Python 2.7.5.

The only thing I find special about running cmd (command shell) is that errors are not echoed to the console like you would expect. Its hard to explain, but if you were to type:

cl.py>log.txt

If an error occured and python would normally return somthing like (any random old error):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    s.s
NameError: name 's' is not defined

the log.txt will not append the error to the file. But anything that is printed normally in python will be appended to the file. But this information is not relevant. :\

Hope you get it working

Comment: yes it is possible to run [full path]\cl.py > log.txt 
Results are the same, and no extra info is in the log file.

Comment: **SOLVED**: I noticed that when running

    `python -v cl.py`

the script worked.

So I have introduced a delay at the end of the script.
`import time # in beginning of script`
`# my socket stuff`
`time.sleep(1.0) # in the end of script`

and the script works fine. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when running python -v cl.py the script worked.

So I have introduced a delay at the end of the script.

```
import time # in beginning of script 
# my socket stuff 
time.sleep(1.0) # in the end of script and the script works fine.
```